# Error preverifying class oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer

Tags: blackberry, java-me, preverify

I am trying to preverify "signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar" file to use it in BlackBerry project

Here is the command im trying. Since it also needs "signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar" to classpath which is already preverified.

> C:\Eclipse_bb\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\bin>
>   preverify.exe -classpath
>   "C:\Eclipse_bb\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.
>   0.0.25\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\
>   rt.jar;C:\Eclipse_bb\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components
>   \bin\output\signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar"
>   signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar

Here i have added classpath of net_rim_api.jar, rt.jar & signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar

It throws below Error

> Error preverifying class
>   oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
>       VERIFIER ERROR 
> oauth/signpost/commonshttp/CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer.wrap(Ljava/lang/Object;)Loauth/signpost/http/HttpRequest;:
>   Illegal type in constant pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/), with source code hosted on github by [kaeppler](https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost/tree/master/signpost-commonshttp4/src/main/java/oauth/signpost/commonshttp), then it appears to be a Java-SE library.  BlackBerry is a Java-ME device, so you will need to find a Java-ME compliant library.  The preverifier errors you are seeing are the first indication that the Java-SE code won't work on BlackBerry.